# Accessing One Drive files offline in VB .Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, onedrive

I am working on an application that stores it's files in the Documents folder to easily sync with One Drive. I need to make them available offline, in case of an outage. I have changed the settings so that I have a local copy. When I click directly on the Excel file in File Explorer, the program opens it with no problem. However, when I try to open the file in my application, I get an error stating "No network found..." etc. Is there another way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub LoadMemberList()
        lstMemberList.Clear()
        Dim mMember As Members
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim range As Excel.Range

        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentYearPath) '***This is where the exception is thrown.
        xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        range = xlSheet.UsedRange
        Dim rs As Object(,) = CType(range.Value, Object(,))
        Dim records As Long = rs.GetUpperBound(0)
        If records > 1 Then
            For x = 2 To records
                mMember.MemberNumber = FormatNumber(rs(x, 1))
                mMember.MemberName = rs(x, 4) + " " + rs(x, 3)
                lstMemberList.Add(mMember)
            Next
        End If
        xlBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        KillExcel()
        xlApp = Nothing
        xlBook = Nothing
        xlSheet = Nothing
        range = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function CurrentYearPath() As String
        Dim CurrentYear As Integer
        CurrentYear = CInt(Format(Now, "yyyy"))
        Return My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments + "\DailyBook\Rosters\Membership" + CurrentYear.ToString + ".xlsx"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/plan-onedrive-enterprise#key-onedrive-features

and you'll find this,

However, if you plan to access a file while disconnected from the internet, you can make the file available offline by right-clicking it, and then selecting Always keep on this device.

Comment: I did all that. As stated, Excel will open the file when the machine is offline. I also have some text files in the same folder that my application opens with no problem. It seems like the Excel object or maybe Microsoft.Office.Interop in general is what's having a fit.

Comment: Anyone else have an answer? I have nothing to go on here.